# MongoDB filter by retrieved value in group

Tags: database, mongodb, count, aggregate, group

I have this collection in MongoDB:

```
[
  { _id: "...", "project": 244, "scanner": "sonarqube", "version": 1 },
  { _id: "...", "project": 244, "scanner": "sonarqube", "version": 2 },
  { _id: "...", "project": 244, "scanner": "sonarqube", "version": 2 },
  { _id: "...", "project": 244, "scanner": "shellcheck", "version": 1 },
  { _id: "...", "project": 244, "scanner": "shellcheck", "version": 2 },
  { _id: "...", "project": 244, "scanner": "shellcheck", "version": 3 },
  { _id: "...", "project": 244, "scanner": "powershell", "version": 2 },
  { _id: "...", "project": 244, "scanner": "powershell", "version": 3 },
  { _id: "...", "project": 244, "scanner": "powershell", "version": 4 },
  { _id: "...", "project": 244, "scanner": "powershell", "version": 4 }
]
```

I would like to return the number of items, grouped by scanner, with the latest (highest) version:

```
{ scanner: "sonarqube", count: 2 }, // All items with sonarqube and version: 2
{ scanner: "shellcheck", count: 1 }, // All items with shellcheck and version: 3
{ scanner: "powershell", count: 2 } // All items with powershell and version: 4
```

So far, I came out with this:

```
db.getCollection("vulnerabilities").aggregate([
{
    $match: { project_id: 422 }
},
{
    $sort: { version: -1 }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$scanner",
        'count': { $first: "$version"},
    }
}
])
```

This returns the latest (highest) version for each group:

```
sonarqube  | 2 |
shellcheck | 3 |
powershell | 4 |
```

Now, I need to tell Mongo:

- filter the item with that version
- group by scanner
- add the count

Any ideas, suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to get the count first, before sorting by version, perhaps:

```
db.getCollection("vulnerabilities").aggregate([
{
    $match: { project_id: 422 }
},
{   
    $group:{
       _id: { scanner: "$scanner", version: "$version"},
       count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
},
{
    $sort: { "_id.version": -1 }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.scanner",
        count: { $first: "$count" },
        version: { $first: "$_id.version" }
    }
}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$max` in the `$group` stage

```
db.test.aggregate([ 
    {$group : {_id : "$scanner", count : {$sum : 1}, version : {$max : "$version"}}}
])
```

or you can `$sort` by version and use `$first`

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$sort : {version: -1}}, 
    {$group : {_id : "$scanner", count : {$sum : 1}, version : {$first : "$version"}}}
])
```